# Elements bigger than column size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a little problem with the bootstrap columns: even though the column width is 316px, an image inside the column gets 317px width, so 1px of the image gets left out uncovered and it looks ugly. Here's some screens:
Here you can see the column width is 316px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqty9.png
Here you can see the image width is 317px AND I pointed out the 1px of the image that gets left out uncovered by the div's: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcNuZ.png

This is the HTML code:

```
<div class = "properties">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 pull-left col-sm-offset-1">
                        <img src = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/parallax/apartment2.png" class = "img-responsive">
                        <div class = "full">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "animborder"></div>
                        <div class = "estatedes">
                            <span>2,000sqft</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "estatetitle">Modern Apartment</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 pull-left col-sm-offset-1">
                        <img src = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/parallax/apartment2.png" class = "img-responsive">
                        <div class = "full">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "animborder"></div>
                        <div class = "estatedes">
                            <span>2,000sqft</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "estatetitle">Modern Apartment</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class = "row">
                    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 pull-left col-sm-offset-1">
                        <img src = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/parallax/apartment2.png" class = "img-responsive">
                        <div class = "full">
                        </div>
                        <div class = "animborder"></div>
                        <div class = "estatedes">
                            <span>2,000sqft</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class = "estatetitle">Modern Apartment</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.properties .row {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

.properties .row > div {
padding: 0px;
}

.properties .row .row > div {
background-color: #e9e9e9;
position: relative;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
max-width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
height: 200px;
padding: 0px;
}

.properties .row .row > div img {
width: 100%;
}

.properties li .full {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #fff;
z-index: 1;

opacity: 0;

transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.properties li:hover {
cursor: pointer;
}

.properties li:hover .full {
opacity: 0.7;
}

.properties li:hover .animborder {
height: 100%;
}

.properties li:hover .estatedes {
background-color: #1abc9c;
color: #fff;
}

.animborder {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
width: 2px;
height: 0%;
background: #1abc9c;
transition: height 0.7s;
z-index: 3;
}

.estatedes {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 33px;
line-height: 33px;
background-color: #e9e9e9;
z-index: 2;

color: #586163;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: 300;
text-indent: 7px;
}

.estatedes span {

}

.estatetitle {
position: absolute;
bottom: 33px;
left: 0px;
background-color: #1abc9c;
padding: 7px;
color: #fff;
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: Set `max-width:100%;` on the images

Comment: You're probably seeing the result of mathematical rounding. Did you try using Bootstrap's `img-responsive` class? That takes care of sizing for you and may resolve the issue. If it doesn't, experiment with `overflow: hidden` on the image's parent element.

Comment: Bootstrap has an [issue blog](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues) - why do you use it than come here to ask questions?

Comment: I'm already using img-responsive class, max-width 100% and overflow:hidden on the parent element and 100% width for the image. Still doesn't work. By the way, if the image is 1px larger, shouldn't the extra 1px be on the right side of the div?

Comment: By the way, the extra 1px doesn't appear on xs and sm devices.

Comment: @skobaljic, i really didn't know. Sorry!

Comment: I really think you should not use Bootstrap for this simple layout.